# jqgrid 4.5.4 jsonReader not using id correctly

Tags: jqgrid

I am defining the id field in the jsonReader.  In jqgrid Version 4.4.5, this works great, but in Version 4.5.4, the id is ignored and the row numbers are always used.  I have created two jsfiddles to demonstrate:

Double click on the row to get the id for that row.

This one correctly displays the id based on what's set in the jsonReader
(Scroll to bottom to see example grid code.  I couldn't find external link to 4.4.5)
Version 4.4.5: http://jsfiddle.net/cVk59/1/

This one incorrectly displays the rowNumber for the id.  It ignores what's set in jsonReader.
Version 4.5.4: http://jsfiddle.net/cnsgH/

```
jsonReader:{ repeatitems:false, id:'0'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use wrong value for `jsonReader.id`. Your current data, returned from the server, have the following format

```js
...
rows: [
    {id: 48803, thingy: "what"}
]
...
```

So the data for a row will be represented by an object like

```js
var obj = {id: 48803, thingy: "what"};
```

To get `id` from the object one need to use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: 'id' }`. Because `id: 'id'` is already default value, you can use just `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }`.

I try to explain the reason why `id: '0'` is wrong property of `jsonReader` in your case. jqGrid just use `obj[jsonReader.id]` to get the id for every row of data. So if you use `jsonReader:{ repeatitems:false, id:'0'}` then jqGrid trying to use `obj['0']` which is wrong (`undefined` value). If you use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: 'id'}` instead (or just `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false}`) then `obj[jsonReader.id]` will be equal to `obj['id']` or `obj.id` and the `id` will be successful read.

The property like `jsonReader: { id: '0' }` will be used if the data, represented a row, is **array** like

```js
var obj = [48803, "what"];
```

In the case `obj[jsonReader.id]` will be equal `obj['0']` or `obj[0]`.